# Handwriting liberties

Tags: handwriting

So this is my first time tying to convert handwriting to text, and its left me with a few questions.

Line 6 Char 2;  I would say is likely せ but I've not come across any instance where stroke 3 can extend below stroke 2, nor can I find a Kanji that comes closer. It this correct?

Line 5 char 4; I would say is likely 這, since I can find a font that has the radical 言 with a vertical carrot on top instead of a bar, however that font doesn't have 這. Is changing top bars to carrots common?

Line 4 char13; 石 is really small, so I would expect to radical attached to 亦 but as I fail to find a matching Kanji, I have to assume the tininess is just inconstancy in Kanji size?

Did I get anything else wrong?

The Hand wring is from an authors response to a reader (typed) question.

[image: Nervous author response]

Text version

```
As Submitted                       As Corrected By Answers
ブルマ！？                           ブルマ！？
ブルマの魅カですか！？                 ブルマの魅カですか！？
ブルマのすそがちょっとズして              ブルマのすそがちょっとズレて
赤くなったフトモモのブル石亦              赤くなったフトモモのブル石亦 
に舌む這ゆせたいです！                 に舌を這わせたいです！
ふせの柔うかい肉体む                   少女の柔らかい肉体を
舌先で、ブルマの尓の息触                舌先で、ブルマの布の感触
む舌のサイドでじながう                   を舌のサイドで感じながら 
思う存分舐め回したいです！               思う存分舐め回したいです！
```

Comment: What the heck kind of pedo-fantasy is this talking about?

Comment: The nature of the question itself is solid, however the nature of the subject matter used in the question is a bit...eh...

Comment: まあまあ、人それぞれですよ！この方は少し、、、特殊な趣味を持ってらっしゃるようですけど、、笑

Comment: From the following context ブル跡 seems to make sense? A quick google search doesn't give any good results so it might have to be a made up word by the author though... Check my edit to my answer and see what you think :/

Comment: This is a reader question at the beginning of book three. As Bloomers are plot element to the main story, the question asked what was the author's interest in bloomers.  The Handwritten response is directly followed by the typed text "Settle down, pervert" The author also included a nervous shaking characterture next to the question, so its just all in good fun.

Comment: Guess the lesson here is that full context helps.  hehehe...

Answer (score 6):

> Line 6 Char 2; I would say is likely せ but I've not come across any instance where stroke 3 can extend below stroke 2, nor can I find a Kanji that comes closer. It this correct?

You wrote ふせ. It should be 少女.

> Line 5 char 4; I would say is likely 這, since I can find a font that has the radical 言 with a vertical carrot on top instead of a bar, however that font doesn't have 這. Is changing top bars to carrots common?

I don't know why you're calling them "carrots" but yes, it's common.

> Line 4 char13; 石 is really small, so I would expect to radical attached to 亦 but as I fail to find a matching Kanji, I have to assume the tininess is just inconstancy in Kanji size?

Yeah, this is strange. I'm hoping someone else will answer on this...
It looks like a radical attached to 亦, but like you I can find no such kanji. ブル石亦 doesn't make any sense either though lol. I would like to say that they just mis-wrote it, but I would be more confident saying that if I could guess what word they actually wanted to write.

EDIT: From the context in the following paragraph, I'm fairly sure they meant to write ブル跡. It doesn't have any useful results on google, but it has a precedent in ブラ跡 which is a common word (ブラジャーの跡→ブラ跡、、、ブルマの跡→ブル跡).

> Did I get anything else wrong?

這**ゆ**せたい should be わ. Yes, writing the start of the 2nd stroke of わ、れ、ね like this is common.

舌**む** should be を.

柔**う**かい should be 柔らかい.

肉体**む** should be を too.

ブルマの**尓** should be 布{ぬの}.

息触む should be 感触を.

舌のサイドで**じながう** should be 感じながら.

Just like reading someone's handwriting in your native language, some of it comes down to figuring it out from the surrounding context/word. The verb 這う is never going to become 這ゆせる, 肉体む doesn't make any sense, etc.

Comment: One more: `ズして` -> `ズレて`.

Comment: Most of that makes sense, (I had a 息 in イドで息じな, Don't know how it got lost in the post) The missing switchback in stroke 2 of を, appears in the same font that I have with the matching 言, I just missed it.

Answer (score 0):

Looking up the character `亦` on its own shows 1) it is a kanji variant of `また（又)`, and 2) that it has several 人名 readings.  So I'm gonna go out on a limb and say `石亦` is possibly the name `いしまた` or `いしばた`.

Comment: Does that make any sense in the context though...?